# Is it possible control RJ45 Ethernet conector pins?

Tags: ethernet, rj-45

My notebook has broken first pin on the RJ45 Ethernet connector. Is it possible to somehow configure that Linux will not use it and instead of it use another?

If I am right there is need only for 3 pins on the Ethernet cable - that would be 100Mbps link.

Comment: Even if you could reassign the signal to another pin, that would mean a different *wire* would be used in the Ethernet cable.  The other end of this Ethernet cable would still be expecting the signals on the standard wire/pin assignment.  So your scheme couldn't work at all.

Comment: Well but I can change wire position with easy, but I can not replace the conector.

Comment: You can buy a USB to Ethernet adapter to bypass this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can’t. Some systems *might* be able to control full, logical ports—allowing you to substitute one port for another but retaining the same identifier—but individual data pins on an port? Nope. That would be overkill and really not a feature anyone wants since replacing an Ethernet port is a relatively simple fix for those who can—and are willing to—solder a new one on.

Besides, if you reassigned a pin on the connector, then what about the cable itself and whatever connector it terminates to on the other end? That others side would need to be aware of the switch and that’s not something that logistically makes sense.

And regarding this:

> If I am right there is need only for 3 pins on Ethernet cable - that
>   would be 100Mbps link.

Nope. An Ethernet cable has 8 pins, but only needs 4 pins for 10/100BT and needs all 8 pins for 1000BT. 3 pins on an RJ45 Ethernet cable = no Ethernet of any kind.

Comment: pins 1,2,3 & 6 - Pin 1 is on the left of the metal contact side. You may be lucky if it's pin 8.

Comment: *"3 pins = no Ethernet of any kind."* -- Older forms of Ethernet used coaxial cable, i.e. one center conductor + shield/return.